# Разделение текста на блоки и запись этих блоков в новые файлы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл test.xml

```
<Файл какой-то текст>
  <ИД какой-то текст>
  </ИД>
</Файл>

<Файл еще какой-то текст>
  <ИД еще какой-то текст>
  </ИД>
</Файл>

<Файл еще какой-то новый то текст>
  <ИД еще какой-то новый текст>
  </ИД>
</Файл>
```

Как видно, блоки теста разделены между собой двумя пустыми строками. Необходимо каждый блок текста поместить в отдельный файл, т.е по нашему примеру, чтобы было три файла:

1.xml

```
<Файл какой-то текст>
  <ИД какой-то текст>
  </ИД>
</Файл>
```

2.xml

```
<Файл еще какой-то текст>
  <ИД еще какой-то текст>
  </ИД>
</Файл>
```

3.xml

```
<Файл еще какой-то новый то текст>
  <ИД еще какой-то новый текст>
  </ИД>
</Файл>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('test.xml', encoding='utf-8') as input_file:
    for i, lines in enumerate(input_file.read().split('\n\n'), start=1):
        with open(str(i) + '.xml', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
            output_file.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Запускаю в pycharm, выдает Process finished with exit code 0 и ничего не происходит, подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Не проверяете рабочий каталог на наличие новых файлов.

Comment: точно, спасибо большое!

Comment: Простите, еще один момент, как к каждому файлу в начале добавить строчку: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>

Comment: разобрался: output_file.writelines('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>' + lines)